# Laravel 5. Saving to database returns error

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my simple Controller:

```
public function addProduct(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product;    
    $product->product_name = $request->product;    

    return $product->save();    
    return back();
}
```

When it is processed `product_name` is saved to `products` table, but I receive the following error as well:

> UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 393: The Response
>   content must be a string or object implementing __toString(),
>   "boolean" given.

Comment: change `return $product->save();` to `$product->save();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you try to return value of $product->save(); call? If you want to save entry and return back then simply

```
$product->save();
return back();
```